# Parsing a local XML file in android

Tags: android, xml

hii everyone am sowmya am brand new to android please can any one help me, am parsing following local xml file ,but am only getting output for 1st question(first set of tags) but 2nd question(repeated tags) am not getting ,,thanx in advance

```
<innertag sampleattribute="innertagAttribute">
<mytag>1)  How did u find the hotel house keeping overall in the year  </mytag>
```

```
    <innertag sampleattribute="innertagAttribute">
<mytag>2)  How do u rate the hotel house keeping overall in the year  </mytag>
```

```
</outertag>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                               am using this as xml handler file
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
package com.itwine;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler{

```
 // ===========================================================
 // Fields
 // ===========================================================

 private boolean in_outertag = false;
 private boolean in_innertag = false;
 private boolean in_mytag = false;




 private boolean in_innertag1 = false;
 private boolean in_mytag1= false;




 private boolean in_innertag2 = false;
 private boolean in_mytag2 = false;

 private XMLDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new XMLDataSet();
 private XMLDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet1 = new XMLDataSet();
 private XMLDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet2 = new XMLDataSet();
 private XMLDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet3 = new XMLDataSet();


 // ===========================================================
 // Getter & Setter
 // ===========================================================

 public XMLDataSet getParsedData() {
      return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
 }

 public XMLDataSet getParsedData1() {
     return this.myParsedExampleDataSet1;
}
 public XMLDataSet getParsedData2() {
     return this.myParsedExampleDataSet2;
}
 public XMLDataSet getParsedData3() {
     return this.myParsedExampleDataSet3;
}


 // ===========================================================
 // Methods
 // ===========================================================
 @Override
 public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
      this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new XMLDataSet();

      this.myParsedExampleDataSet1 = new XMLDataSet();

      this.myParsedExampleDataSet2 = new XMLDataSet();

      this.myParsedExampleDataSet3 = new XMLDataSet();
 }

 @Override
 public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
      // Nothing to do
 }

 /** Gets be called on opening tags like:
  * <tag>
  * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
  * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
 @Override
 public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
           String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
      if (localName.equals("outertag")) 
      {
           this.in_outertag = true;
      }



      else if (localName.equals("innertag"))
      {
           this.in_innertag = true;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("mytag")) 
      {
           this.in_mytag = true;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("tagwithnumber")) 
      {
           // Extract an Attribute
           String attrValue = atts.getValue("thenumber");
           int i = Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
           myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedInt(i);
      }

      else if (localName.equals("innertag1"))
      {
           this.in_innertag1 = true;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("mytag1")) 
      {
           this.in_mytag1 = true;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("tagwithnumber1")) 
      {
           // Extract an Attribute
           String attrValue = atts.getValue("thenumber");
           int j = Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
           myParsedExampleDataSet1.setExtractedInt(j);
      }

      else if (localName.equals("innertag2"))
      {
           this.in_innertag2 = true;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("mytag2")) 
      {
           this.in_mytag2 = true;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("tagwithnumber2")) 
      {
           // Extract an Attribute
           String attrValue = atts.getValue("thenumber");
           int k = Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
           myParsedExampleDataSet2.setExtractedInt(k);
      }

      else if (localName.equals("QIA")) 
      {
           // Extract an Attribute



      }


 }


 /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
  * </tag> */
 @Override
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
           throws SAXException {



      if (localName.equals("outertag")) 
      {
           this.in_outertag = false;
      }
      else if (localName.equals("innertag")) 

      {
           this.in_innertag = false;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("mytag")) 

      {
           this.in_mytag = false;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("tagwithnumber")) {
           // Nothing to do here
      }


      else if (localName.equals("innertag1")) 

      {
           this.in_innertag1 = false;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("mytag1")) 

      {
           this.in_mytag1 = false;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("tagwithnumber1")) {
           // Nothing to do here
      }

      else if (localName.equals("innertag2")) 

      {
           this.in_innertag2 = false;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("mytag2")) 

      {
           this.in_mytag2 = false;
      }

      else if (localName.equals("tagwithnumber2")) {
           // Nothing to do here
      }
 }


 /** Gets be called on the following structure:
  * <tag>characters</tag> */
 @Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
      if(this.in_mytag){
      myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
 }

      else if(this.in_mytag1){
          myParsedExampleDataSet1.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
     }

      else if(this.in_mytag2){
          myParsedExampleDataSet2.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
     }
}
```

}

Comment: The main idea of parsing is to extract data enclosed between some tags, that usually repeat more than once. Also, the fact that you have the xml data source local or remote doesn't require a different parser. Your problem seems to be the way you store the data after you retrieve it by parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've done the xml parsing in android. check this link for the build..

[compliantbox.com/XmlParsingcompliant.zip](http://www.compliantbox.com/XmlParsingcompliant.zip)

just replace the url with your local address...................

Comment: thanx for ur reply,,but data in that url contains junk data  what data should i hav in local file,,,,i hav little confusion in the syntax,,ill u please give me the code which parses local xml which contains repeatative tags(i mean same tag used multiple times)

Comment: thak u very much for providing that zip file it helped me a lot

Comment: hii prateek Raj ill u please give me XMLComlaint.java file in whic URL is replaced by Local xml path,,am not getting the syntax ,,am wating for ur reply,,,thanx in adwance

Comment: ya but am not getting syntax to change url to local xml path,,can u give me path changed XMLComlaint.java file? thanx in advance

Comment: did you use IIS ? 
if you did everything right your local xml link should look something like this:
http://192.168.1.92/testapp/..../XMLS/xmlformat.xml

Comment: thanx for ur reply,, that link ur provided is not getting open.....am trying to parse local file  xml/file.xml (which is there in ur project "xmlParsingComplient" am doing modification on ur project only after successfull parsing of local file in ur project ill use that idea in my application,,so ill u tell me how to write syntax to change url path to local xml path,,(am brand new to android)

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in your code is such that, if condition is true it comes out at the first instance..so your code cannot see the second mytag.

If are allowed to change, you can very well change the tag names:
mytag11
mytag22

I think, this should work.

Comment: thanx for your reply,,ya that case is working,,but i need to use same tag repeatedly (same tag used multiple times)

Comment: Then you need to store the tag string values in a data structure and process them one by one. The current implementation will always come out after first mytag.

Comment: oh ok please ill u give me one small example code which stores the tag string values in data structure ,thanx in advance